# How to code a qualified association in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, uml

Note that I am not a expert in UML.

Usually I think on an class diagram (in its later stage of design) being parallel to the implementation code. I want to know how implement a qualified association in PHP (or another OOP language like Java). Maybe it is only a concept in UML that can be implemented in any way, or it is intended to be implemented in a well-defined way. I just know that the qualifier value is used to select target objects.

Here is a example of a qualified association, from the book "The Unified Modeling Language Reference Manual, 2° Edition"

[image: Qualified association example]

The questions are:

Is the qualifier value (or values) to be like an attribute (or attributes) of the qualified class?

Can I avoid the use of qualified associations? Why?

**How to code a qualified association** like that from the example? Exists several ways to do it? What is the best?

Sorry if it is not clear, or redundant, or stupid question. I appreciate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My PHP times are too long ago to remember the right syntax, but basically the qualifier denotes the key you would use to look up something in a hash map (associative array).

P.S. This might be an example:

```
$customers = array(
  "account" => $person,
  ...
);
```

So within your `Bank` class you look up the `Person` with the key `account` in the `$customers` array. Note that the name of the latter is taken from the context and not explicitly stated in UML. There is no need for a qualifier. It's just some extra information the UML modeler passes to the programmer. Also there is no dedicated way, but the above would probably the most convenient one in PHP. And of course, since your picture is just an excerpt, it mostly makes just sense if you have more than one key (e.g. `credibility` and other things that might be of interest additionally in the `$customers` array).

Comment: Thank you, I'm more informed now =)